# Probability question involving paths through computer network

Tags: probability

I am working the following probability problem which I came across online:

> A computer network has 5 paths to its destination. Each path has a 20% chance of working and each path is independent. Am I guaranteed that at least one path will work?

I first answered it like:

> P(1st path working OR 2nd path working OR 3rd path working OR 4th path
>   working OR 5th path working) = 0.2 + 0.2 + 0.2 + 0.2 + 0.2 = 1

but apparently that is not correct. Can someone explain why?

Thanks!

Comment: So if the probability that each path works were $30\%$ instead of $20\%$, would you have said that the probability of at least one path working is $0.3+0.3+0.3+0.3+0.3=1.5$?

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing has no right to work, because if there had been 6 paths each with 20% reliability, the same method would yield a probability of $1.2$ -- but probabilities cannot be more than $1$.

Your fundamental error is that you're *adding* independent probabilities. Doing so is *never* correct, because it amounts to ignoring the possibility that both independent events occur at the same time (which they can do because they're *independent*).

The smart way to do questions like this is to compute the probability that all paths will *fail* at the same time (which involves multiplication which *is* allowed for independent probabilities), and then invert that result.

Comment: Thanks. So under what conditions do you add probabilities?

Comment: Probabilities of events that are known _never to happen at the same time_ can be added freely. (And addition is used internally in the correct rule for independent events: $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A)P(B)$ when $A$ and $B$ are independent).

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that the probability isn't $1$, just imagine the scenario where all paths fail. Surely this scenario can happen since each path has a positive probability of failing and they are independent.

The probability that at least one path will work is $1 - P(\text{all paths fail})$. Since the paths are independent, the probability that all paths fail simultaneously is exactly the product of their probabilities to fail.

Thus, $P(\text{at least one path works}) = 1 - P(\text{all paths fail}) = 1 - (0.80)^5 = 0.67232$.

Comment: @Peter: Yeah, read it too quickly. Fixed now.